# What is wrong with this syntax?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have #imported the FirstViewController.h

and i get the error "expected ':' before '.' token"

```
NSString *myString = RoutineTitle.text;

[FirstViewController.routines addObject:myString];
```

What am i doing wrong? Someone please enlighten me!

Thanks,

Sam

Comment: Could you please show how you defined this "routines" property/member?

Comment: Please give some more information about your variables. People need to know what is `RoutineTitle` and what is `routtines`. What is `text` inside `RoutineTitle`, is `RoutineTitle` a class or an instance variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is "routines" a member of FirstViewController?  It sort of looks like "FirstViewController" is a class name, not an instance name, but I could be mistaken.

If you are in "FirstViewController", and "routines" is a variable in scope that is an NSArray or NSMutableArray or similar, just change it to:

```
NSString *myString = RoutineTitle.text;

[routines addObject:myString];
```

Comment: i had to make an instance of the class.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax

```
[FirstViewController.routines addObject:myString];
```

is used in languages (I think other than objective c not in objective c) to assign values to static variables.

So if `routines` is an object of a static array you should define a static method in the FirstViewController class and calling that method you should add this object like:

```
+(void)addObjectToRoutines:(NSString *)string{//In the FirstViewController class
[routines addObject:string];
}
```

and from the class you are in just do this

```
NSString *myString = RoutineTitle.text;

[FirstViewController addObjectToRoutines:myString];
```

Now if its a stance variable you should first make a object of your class like:

```
FirstViewController *viewCont = [[FirstViewController alloc] init];
[[viewCont routines] addObject:myString];
```

Hope this helps.(The answer is given as my pridiction is that FirstViewController is class name not a variable, may be I am mistaken)

Thanks,

Madhup

Comment: yea you were write, i was using the class.routine instead of classInstance.routine.

Answer (score 0):

From the import statement I assume that `FirstViewController` is the name of a class:

```
#imported the FirstViewController.h
```

You are possibly trying to access a variable inside that class which should be some kind of collection supporting `addObject:`:

```
[FirstViewController.routines addObject:myString];
```

However you need to use the object name not the class name, something like (I don't know how your code looks like):

```
FirstViewController * aFirstViewController
            = [[FirstViewController alloc] initWithSomething ....];
```

Now assuming that `FirstViewController` has a collection `routines` and appropriate `property` declaration you could do:

```
[aFirstViewController.routines addObject:myString];
```